# Java: Canvas.drawline, how to draw a thicker line

Tags: java, canvas, line

Im trying to draw a lightning bolt on my canvas but the line is only one pixel wide. How can I make the line thicker?

```
 canvas.drawLine(lightningBoltArray[i].startXArray[k],lightningBoltArray[i].startYArray[k],lightningBoltArray[i].endXArray[k],lightningBoltArray[i].endYArray[k],paintHalfAlpha);
```

Is the trick somewhere in the settings of the applied paint?

Comment: Much better to look at `Graphics2D` and `Stroke` and `Paint`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing something that allows you do to this you're probably painting incorrectly.  Assuming that this is in a `JPanel` instance.  It will also work for `paint(Graphics g)` in `Canvas` but most painting in Java is done using `Swing`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
   // other stuff
   float width = 3f;
   BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(width);
   g2d.setStroke(stroke);
   g2d.drawLine(...);
   // more stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution was to do lightningPaint.setstrokewidth(5)

Comment: Are you using any external libraries you didn't mention?

Comment: Nope. I probably should but Im just using the Java Canvas as my Graphics engine

Comment: So where does `lightningPaint.setstrokewidth` come from?

Comment: It's native to the Paint class

Comment: You must be using some other feature because there is no Paint class. There is a Paint interface.  So you're not using Guava or something like that?